# How can I get away from a loop?

Tags: python, loops

So I have been trying to play around abit with monitor - For those who doesn't know what monitoring is - basically what it means is that you are checking something etc element, url or whatever in a certain time and check again if it has been changed.

This is what I have done and...

```
url = 'mrcnoir'

while True:
        try:
            password_page = requests.get('https://{}.com'.format(url), timeout=5)
            password_page.raise_for_status()

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            print('Error checking password page! - https://{}.com'.format(url) + ' - ' + str(err))
            continue



        else:
            # *************---If password up---**************

            if ('password' in password_page.url):
                        # Password page is up
                        print('Password page is up! - ' + 'https://{}.com'.format(url))
                        if not ('password' in password_page.url):

                            # No password page -> password page


                            # *************---Send---**************

                            print("SENDING...1")

                            time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))


            # *************---If password down---**************

            else:
                # Password page is down
                print('Password page is down! - ' + 'https://{}.com'.format(url))
                if ('password' in password_page.url):

                    # Password page -> no password page


                    # *************---Send---**************

                    print("SENDING...2") #<---- If it comes in here - it will be stuck forever and just keep posting this print...
                    time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))

        # *************---Retry between 6-12 random.---**************
        finally:
            time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))
```

The issue im having is at the bottom where it prints "SENDING...2" - What happened is that it just continues to print out the SENDING...2 all the time which means it been stuck in the loop -

Basically what I want to do is that whenever it comes to the second Else part it should print it out once and then continue to "monitor" and check until there is new changes. Meaning it will be needing to wait until it appears/password in the url.

How could I in that case make it happen?

Comment: shouldn't you check for the response text? ... instead of url, so use *password_page.text*

Comment: your if statements make no sense either

Comment: @user2413548 The reason I have the other is that I want to know whenever the page is up and when the page is down. The plan was to notify me by discord later on whenever the Password is up and down and that's the reason why I have the if and else statements. - Thats why I wonder now like how I could make it possible send print in SENDING 1 and SENDING 2 without having an stuck loop inside each other. - Also that im sure I want to use the URL because the changes will become from the URL and not the text itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = 'mrcnoir'
last_status = False
while True:
        try:
            password_page = requests.get('https://{}.com'.format(url), timeout=5)
            password_page.raise_for_status()

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            print('Error checking password page! - https://{}.com'.format(url) + ' - ' + str(err))
            continue

        else:
            # *************---If password up---**************

            if 'password' in password_page.url and last_status == False:
                # Password page is up
                last_status = True
                print('Password page is up! - ' + 'https://{}.com'.format(url))

                time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))


            # *************---If password down---**************

            elif not 'password' in password_page.url and last_status == True:
                # Password page is down
                last_status = False
                print('Password page is down! - ' + 'https://{}.com'.format(url))
                time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))

        # *************---Retry between 6-12 random.---**************
        finally:
            time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))
```

Comment: But that means it will print out the "password is down" everytime, wont it?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Did you even try it?

Comment: I did and I could say that it did print out the Password is down everytime while it was down which in that case is the mrcnoir aswell. What I wish is to only do it once - meaning etc it is mrcnoir.com/password and whenever it turns to mrcnoir.com only - it should notify me with a print and only do it once.. Meaning that the next thing it gonna do is to requests and see whenever it turns to password up meaning mrcnoir.com/password and once it hits it - it should print out that and in a loop like that.

Comment: That's exactly what this code does.  It only notifies when there is a change of state: password -> no password, or no password -> password.  If that's not what you want, then you need to restate your question another way.

Comment: No you are the correct way - the thing is that whenever I use ur code - when it hits the elif statement - it will print out the Password page is down everytime which is fine - but what if I want it to send it only once in that case instead of all the time? Imagine getting tons of prints instead of just knowing it once.

Comment: I took out all the extraneous code from your original post, so hopefully now it is easier to understand.  It does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Yeah there we go! Well what I noticed is that it will always say page up but never page down on the first start up - what I did was to change last_status = False to `last_status = None` - Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import random
import time

url = 'https://mrcnoir.com/account/login'
errState = False

while True:
    try:
        password_page = requests.get('{}'.format(url), timeout=5)
        password_page.raise_for_status()

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        if not errState:            
            print('Error checking password page! - {}'.format(url) + ' - ' + str(err))
            print("SENDING...2")   # <-----------------
            errState = True
        continue

    else:
        # *************---If password up---**************

        if ('password' in password_page.text):
            # Password page is up
            print('Password page is up! - ' + '{}'.format(url))
            print("SENDING...1")
            errState = False


        #else:
        #    # Password page is down ???
        #    # this is not a useful test, if it is down you get an exception and
        #    # should handle it there
        #    print('Password page is down! - ' + '{}'.format(url))
        #    print("SENDING...2") #<---- If it comes in here - it will be stuck forever and just keep posting this print...

    # *************---Retry between 6-12 random.---**************
    finally:
        time.sleep(random.randint(6, 12))
```

Comment: The reason I have the other is that I want to know whenever the page is up and when the page is down. The plan was to notify me by discord later on whenever the Password is up and down and that's the reason why I have the if and else statements. - Thats why I wonder now like how I could make it possible send print in SENDING 1 and SENDING 2 without having an stuck loop inside each other.

Comment: Are you sure, I mean after it has been printed, will it continue to print all the time or will it just loop and check for the new updates?

Comment: ok different interpretation of 'loop stuck' ... in that case you need to keep track of the state

Comment: What would you recommend me to do in that case? - Because bascially my idea is that etc if there is a password... Just update until the password is gone - then notify for me with a print that there has been removed password. After that update the site and wait until the password is getting changed to password up. Then notify and on and on like that.

Comment: added *errState*, that will make it show the msg only once

Comment: I dont think it is what I wanted to do, Basically what gonna happened with your code is that it will only print out the error that can happen and when page is up. - Basically what happens when monitoring a URL is that it is etc mrcnoir.com (meaning page is down) and it can automatic be redirected to mrcnoir.com/password (even though you enter mrcnoir.com) and thats the reason why I requests only the mrcnoir.com. And also why I want to see whenever the page is down and up. Do you ish ~ understand my point abit better now and why I need the other password is down aswell? Unless im totally blind